# How to apply a conditional class attribute depending on the current routing?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a navigation component in my App which has several links to different pages which will be accessed via routing. I want to show a navigation item as "active" if the router is currently on the same page that the link refers. I tried several things till I ended up with the following code which dynamically sets the CSS class depending on the current route:

template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class.bind="overviewClass"><a href="#/batch/overview">Overview</a></li>
      <li class.bind="completedJobsClass"><a href="#/batch/completed-jobs">Completed Jobs</a></li>
      <li class.bind="jobDefinitionsClass"><a href="#/batch/job-definitions">Job Definitions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

ViewModel:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class Navigation {
  constructor(private router: Router){
  }

  get overviewClass(){
    return this.isActive("overview") ? "active" : "";
  }

  get completedJobsClass(){
    return this.isActive("completed-jobs") ? "active" : "";
  }

  get jobDefinitionsClass(){
    return this.isActive("job-definitions") ? "active" : "";
  }

  isActive(routeName: string){
    if( this.router.currentInstruction != null && this.router.currentInstruction.config.name == routeName ){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

This code indeed works as expected. My problem is that I need to find a **more dynamic** solution because this solution does not scale. Currently, I'll have to add **a getter for each navigation item** I need to implement.

I tried to use a function instead of a getter, but the problem was in all my cases that the value of `this.router.currentInstruction` was null.

Is there an efficient way to implemented a function with a parameter so that I can bind it from the template without having to add a function or getter for each link?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in way to check if the route you're on is the active one. Aurelia router already gives you this property. If there's some route you don't want to be added to the UI you can use the `nav` attribute on your route definition and set it to `false` and it won't be added to the `route.navigation` array.

Like on this example:

router configuration

```
 { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index',   nav: true },
  { route: 'users/:id/detail', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' },
```

where you want to display your menu

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It is worth mentioning that you can access the URL using the "href" property and the display name can be specified using the "title" property. The "href" property does not need to be set manually it gets its value from the "route" property if specified. My final solution looks like this:

`<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}"><a href="${row.href}">${row.title}</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom attribute:

// is-active.js

```
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import { inject, customAttribute, DOM, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

const EVENT_NAME = 'router:navigation:success';

@inject(DOM.Element, Router, EventAggregator)
@customAttribute('is-active')
@bindable({ name: 'route' })
@bindable({ name: 'selector', defaultValue: 'is-active' })
export class IsActiveCustomAttribute {

    constructor(element, router, eventAggregator) {
        this.router = router;
        this.element = element;
        this.ea = eventAggregator;
    }

    attached() {
        this.subscriber = this.ea.subscribe(EVENT_NAME, this.handler.bind(this));
    }

    detached() {
        this.subscriber.dispose();
    }

    handler() {
        let config = this.router.currentInstruction.config;
        let currentRoute = config.name;
        let hasSelector = this.element.classList.contains(this.selector);
        let matchChildren = config.route.split('/', 1)[0] === this.route;

        if (this.route === currentRoute || matchChildren) {
            if (!hasSelector) {
                this.element.classList.add(this.selector);
            }
        } else if (hasSelector) {
            this.element.classList.remove(this.selector);
        }
    }
}
```

// html

```
<nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" 
        is-active="route: courses" 
        route-href="route: courses">Courses</a>

    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" 
        is-active="route: freebies" 
        route-href="route: freebies">Freebies</a>

    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" 
        is-active="route: blog" 
        route-href="route: blog">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sure this works and you use it in production I guess. But for me the answer from @maximedubois is what I was looking for. This solution seems to be the way to go using the framework to do the "hard work".